# Deduplacting the messages at Kafka Producer side

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api, producer-consumer

I have an uses to **process CDC through Kafka SQL connector**, I have an order with muliple items inside. If there is any change in the cart items , I need to send the respective order_id to consumer kafka topic.
**I am using java8 , kafka and springboot.**

This is working fine with Spring Kafka Producer code with an issue.

```
Issue : When multiple iteams are touched in an order, those many duplicate order_ids are being sent to kafka topic.
At the consumer side duplicate order_ids  are received for processing which is slowing down the entire processing by wasting resources.

To fix the issue , i need to drop duplicates or send distinct order_ids in an timing window say every 30 secs , how it could be done at Kafka Producer side service ?
```

**Please note my producer services are deployed on kubenaties pods.**